# add multiple circles in a div using circles.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I want to add multiple circles in a div, which should look like all the three circles present i row . How do I achieve by using circles.js.

HTML :

Below is the js code used to generate

```
var myCircle = Circles.create(
            {
                id:         'circles-1',
                radius:     60,
                value:      7,
                maxValue:   100,
                width:      10,
                text:       function(value){return value + '%';},
                colors:     ['#FFF', '#FFA500'],
                duration:   400,
                wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
                textClass:  'circles-text'
            }
```

Comment: Do you want all three using only one Div ? not multiple divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires to have **three separate Divs** to render each of the circle separately.

Below you can use to show **three circle in a row**.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="circles.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #canvas .circle {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 1em;
    } 
  </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="canvas">
      <div class="circle" id="circles-1"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="circles-2"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="circles-3"></div>
     </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
            var myCircle = Circles.create({
                id:         'circles-1',
                radius:     60,
                value:      43,
                maxValue:   100,
                width:      10,
                text:       "Apple",
                colors:     ['#D3B6C6', '#4B253A'],
                duration:   400,
                wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
                textClass:  'circles-text'
            }); 

            var myCircle2 = Circles.create({
                id:         'circles-2',
                radius:     40,
                value:      43,
                maxValue:   100,
                width:      10,
                text:       "Banana",
                colors:     ['#FCE6A4', '#EFB917'],
                duration:   400,
                wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
                textClass:  'circles-text'
            }); 

            var myCircle3 = Circles.create({
                id:         'circles-3',
                radius:     40,
                value:      43,
                maxValue:   100,
                width:      10,
                text:       "Mango",
                colors:     ['#BEE3F7', '#F8F9B6'],
                duration:   400,
                wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
                textClass:  'circles-text'
            }); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly:

HTML:

```
<div class="cicles">
    <div class="circle" id="circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="circle-2"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myCircle1 = Circles.create(
        {
            id:         'circle-1',
            radius:     60,
            value:      7,
            maxValue:   100,
            width:      10,
            text:       function(value){return value + '%';},
            colors:     ['#FFF', '#FFA500'],
            duration:   400,
            wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
            textClass:  'circles-text'
        }

var myCircle2 = Circles.create(
        {
            id:         'circle-2',
            radius:     60,
            value:      7,
            maxValue:   100,
            width:      10,
            text:       function(value){return value + '%';},
            colors:     ['#FFF', '#FFA500'],
            duration:   400,
            wrpClass:   'circles-wrp',
            textClass:  'circles-text'
        }
```

Comment: This really helped, thanks. I am new to this. Is there a way to change the background color of the circle and change the font-size as well???